# What to do if the mongodb index is very large

Tags: mongodb

**my table data：**

Storage size:51.06 MB

Documents:1.7 M

Avg. document size:93.00 B

Indexes:3

Total index size:129.21 MB

[image]
[image]

Is it still possible to optimize the size of the index?

Comment: That's not particularly large, and indexes clearly make for more efficient queries.

Comment: Why do you consider 129MB as "very large"?

Comment: @TimRoberts This is the first time I use mongodb, and it is the first time I have contact with so much data, because the index is larger than the data, so I feel it is relatively large

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit If not big is best, I don't need to optimize anything, because my data structure is simple, only two ids, so I feel big

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I think index `friend_1_read_1` is simply not needed, drop it. Just create `friend_1_user_1`. Query might be little slower, but you ask for less index size and not for query performance.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, because the query is slow, add it. Keep it. For the sake of query speed